# ¿Como puedo realizar un update en una relación muchos a muchos EntityFramework 6 con Repositorio y UnityOfWork?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La Tabla intermedia no tiene "PrimaryKey" (llave primaria). Se trata de una tabla con identificadores compuestos, así que por eso no aparece.

mi pregunta es ¿Como realizar un update en una relación muchos a muchos EntityFramework 6 con Repositorio y UnityOfWork?

Comment: tiene algun codigo de repository y UoW que estes implementando ? mas que nada para partir de alli, ya que hay variaciones de como se puede desarrollar

Comment: faltan 2 días para 1 mes, no hay comentario por parte del autor de la pregunta, que se debería hacer?

Answer (score 2):

Al establecer una relación de muchos a muchos con **Entity Framework** se tienen dos propiedades de navegación de tipo colección (una en cada entidad), que permiten actualizar los valores de dicha relación.

En este caso el código de las entidades que se generarían para este modelo serían algo así:

```
public class Usuario
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identificador del usuario
    /// </summary>
    public int IdUsuario { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Propiedad de navegación relación muchos a muchos Usuarios-Compromisos
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Collection<Compromiso> Compromisoes { get; set; }
}

public class Compromiso
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identificador del compromiso
    /// </summary>
    public int IdCompromido { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Propiedad de navegación relación muchos a muchos Usuarios-Compromisos
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Collection<Usuario> Usuarioes { get; set; }
}
```

y el DbContext que se tendría sería parecido a este:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarioes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Compromiso> Compromisoes { get; set; }
}
```

Ahora imaginemos que existe un Compromiso con Id = 3 y un Usuario con Id = 1, la relación entre ellos se establecería de esta forma:

```
int idUsuario = 1;
int idCompromiso = 3;

using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var usuario = context.Usuarioes.Find(idUsuario);
    var compromiso = context.Compromisoes.Find(idCompromiso);

    // Establecer la relación entre el usuario y el compromiso
    compromiso.Usuarioes.Add(usuario);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

El problema de trabajar así es que en la propiedad `Usuarioes` se van a cargar los datos de todos los usuarios asociados al compromiso aunque esta carga se puede evitar accediendo al [ObjectStateManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) y estableciendo la relación a bajo nivel:

```
int idUsuario = 1;
int idCompromiso = 3;

using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var usuario = context.Usuarioes.Find(idUsuario);
    var compromiso = context.Compromisoes.Find(idCompromiso);

    // Establecer la relación entre el usuario y el compromiso
    var stateManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
    stateManager.ChangeRelationshipState<Compromiso>(
       compromiso, 
       usuario, 
       c => c.Usuarioes, 
       EntityState.Added);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

En cuanto a como hacer esto usando los patrones **Repositorio** y **UnitOfWork**, como apuntaba [Leandro Tuttini](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2600/leandro-tuttini) en los comentarios, depende mucho de como se implementen estos patrones porque hay varias formas de hacerlo.

Una opción sería siguiendo la implementación del repositorio genérico de [este](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) artículo de la documentación de ASP.NET y consistía en añadir dos métodos, uno para añadir elementos a la relación y otro para eliminarlos.

La implementación de estos métodos sería así:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    ...

    public virtual void AddRelatedEntity(
        TEntity sourceEntity,
        object targetEntity,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> navigationPropertySelector)
    {
        var stateManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
        stateManager.ChangeRelationshipState<TEntity>(
            sourceEntity, targetEntity, navigationPropertySelector, EntityState.Added);
    }

    public virtual void RemoveRelatedEntity(
        TEntity sourceEntity,
        object targetEntity,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> navigationPropertySelector)
    {
        var stateManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
        stateManager.ChangeRelationshipState<TEntity>(
            sourceEntity, targetEntity, navigationPropertySelector, EntityState.Deleted);
    }
}
```

Y el código para establecer la relación entre ambas entidades usando estos patrones sería el siguiente:

```
int idUsuario = 1;
int idCompromiso = 3;

using (var unitOfWork = new MyUnitOfWork())
{
    var usuario = unitOfWork.UsuarioRepository.GetByID(idUsuario);
    var compromiso = unitOfWork.CompromisoRepository.GetByID(idCompromiso);

    // Establecer la relación entre el usuario y el compromiso
    unitOfWork.UsuarioRepository.AddRelatedEntity(
        usuario, 
        compromiso, 
        u => u.Compromisoes);

    unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

> **Nota:** El código de todos los ejemplos está simplificado al máximo para que 
>   se entienda mejor, por lo que no es apto para usarlo en producción